# Не могу собрать проект на ionic + angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic

Проект делал не я, мне передали на поддержку. Если честно, ionic и angular не очень знаю. Надо собрать проект и запустить на телефоне. Запускаю такой командой

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

И получаю такую ошибку

```
 Cannot find type definition file for '@types'.
```

Пробовал разные советы, ничего не помогает

Comment: `npm install` делали? сорри за вопрос, если что :)

Comment: да, уже несколько раз